# Can I do something when any thread terminates?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi

Is there any way to set up a callback that will be called when any thread within my program terminates?  The only information I would need is the ThreadID of the dying thread.  (Not a duplicate of a few similar questions that are asking about .NET; I need a way to do this in native code.)